# i want to arrange the topics by date and display its category

Tags: database, categories

For my college project i am making a forum.

i want to arrange the topics by date and display its category with each topic.
My forum shows output as-

Let there are 3 categories-1)animal 2)science 3)travel.
If i asked my latest question in travel category then my answer will be shown at the bottom.
As questions(topics) are showing according to categories. 
Topics are arranged by date inside categories.As if i again ask another question in travel category my question(topic) will be shown at 2nd last position.

I want that my latest question(topic) should come at top after i ask my question(topic).

I want to reverse this.

i have done only php and some css in my course. so i don't know more about database.

---

If u want to see image of the view of my forum website. 
please click the dropbox link below- 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tty5vhj0yi298pf/forum%20help.png

---

this is my database.

---

DATABASE name= data`;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
`cat_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cat_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `cat_name` (`cat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
 `post_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_content` text NOT NULL,
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `post_topic` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `post_by` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `topic_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `topic_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `topic_cat` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `topic_by` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_level` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is 
my index

---

```
<?php
//create_cat.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';



$sql = "SELECT
        categories.cat_id,
        categories.cat_name,
        categories.cat_description,
        COUNT(topics.topic_id) AS topics
    FROM
        categories
    LEFT JOIN
        topics
    ON
        topics.topic_id = categories.cat_id
    GROUP BY
        categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description, categories.cat_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The categories could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
else
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'No categories defined yet.';
}
else
{


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {               





            //fetch last topic for each cat
                $topicsql = "SELECT
                                topic_id,
                                topic_subject,
                                topic_date,
                                topic_cat
                            FROM
                                topics
                            WHERE
                                topic_cat = " . $row['cat_id'] . "
                            ORDER BY
                                topic_date
                            DESC
                            LIMIT
                                1";

                $topicsresult = mysql_query($topicsql);

                if(!$topicsresult)
                {
                    echo 'Last topic could not be displayed.';
                }
                else
                {
                    //if(mysql_num_rows($topicsresult) == 0)
                    //{
                    //  echo 'no topics</br></br>';
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                        while($topicrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($topicsresult))
                        echo '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicrow['topic_id'] . '">            <h4>' . $topicrow['topic_subject'] . '<a href="category.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">    </h4>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></br></a> at ' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($topicrow['topic_date'])).'</br></br>';

                }

    }
}

}


?><br />
<?php


include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but I believe you want to move topics to the left side of the SELECT statement. This query would return topics ordered newest to oldest, with matching category information (if available). If the category information is not available then c1.cat_name and c1.cat_description would be null.

```
SELECT t1.topic_id, t1.topic_subject, t1.topic_date, t1.topic_cat, c1.cat_name, c1.cat_description     
FROM topics t1 LEFT JOIN categories c1 ON t1.topic_id = c1.cat_id
ORDER BY t1.topic_date desc
```